# Dropwizard Hibernate cannot connect to Oracle Autonomous Database

Tags: dropwizard, oracle-autonomous-db

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Autonomous Database (setup a trial) using DropWizard hibernate.

This is my application.yml

```
  database:
    driverClass: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    user: ***
    password: ***
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcps://adb.uk-london-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/ga49252925e7ea8_taskerdbrh4j_medium.adb.oraclecloud.com?wallet_location=/Users/gp/Downloads/Wallet_TaskerDBrh4j
    properties:
      charSet: UTF-8
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s
  validationQuery: "/* MyApplication Health Check */ select 1 from dual "
  minSize: 8
  maxSize: 32
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
```

I downloaded the wallet to `/Users/gp/Downloads/Wallet_TaskerDBrh4j`

However when I run the application I get this a huge stack track with these bits in:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: IO Error Received fatal alert: handshake_failure, connect lapse 55 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(T4CConnection.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:690)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1086)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:90)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:728)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:769)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:697)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:121)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:110)
    at io.dropwizard.db.ManagedPooledDataSource.start(ManagedPooledDataSource.java:37)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryManager.start(SessionFactoryManager.java:22)
    at io.dropwizard.lifecycle.JettyManaged.doStart(JettyManaged.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:60)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:98)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
    at garryp.Application.main(Application.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IO Error Received fatal alert: handshake_failure, connect lapse 55 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(T4CConnection.java:920)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IO Error Received fatal alert: handshake_failure, connect lapse 55 ms.
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:202)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:354)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:2155)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:652)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IO Error Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.unwrap(SSLSocketChannel.java:674)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.unwrapHandshakeMessage(SSLSocketChannel.java:623)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.doSSLHandshake(SSLSocketChannel.java:461)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.write(SSLSocketChannel.java:149)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:361)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOConnectPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOConnectPacket.java:256)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:157)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:627)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:422)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.unwrap(SSLSocketChannel.java:670)
    ... 37 more
```

Pretty sure something in the URL is wrong, but no idea what. Both DropWizard and Oracle Cloud documentation is very poor so struggling for ideas.

Comment: Which version of Oracle JDBC? Which JDK version?

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace wallet_location with TNS_ADMIN and refer to the same location where you have unzipped the client credentials?
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcps://adb.uk-london-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/ga49252925e7ea8_taskerdbrh4j_medium.adb.oraclecloud.com?TNS_ADMIN=/Users/gp/Downloads/Wallet_TaskerDBrh4j